# how to embed html code in asp.net (VB)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have multiline textbox... if I type the HTML code snippet in the TextBox and click on submit button, then the HTML coding will run of Default .aspx with the dimension 920 * 220 pixels...

How to do that using asp.net (VB)

Comment: @user522211 Could you explain more? Why don't implement this in XHTML markup?

Comment: Simply format i want when i type some html code snippet in www.orkut.com scrapbook then it will convert in images... how to do that in vb.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create images on the fly using ASP.NET System.Drawing namespace. Within that namespace there are Text related methods which you can use to write text in your image.

Here is a short tutorial: http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/graphics/Drawing-Csharp.aspx